# Change size of the axis text in r

Tags: r, plot, axis, r-caret

I have model created by train function from caret. I want to plot this object and increase size of text and title of axis. I found how to change size of titles, but I couldn't find how to do it for text on the axis. Example code for my problem below:

```
library(caret)
m <- train(mpg~., data = mtcars, tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(2,4,5)))
plot(m, xlab = list(font=3, cex = 5), ylab = list(font=3, cex = 5))
```

I tried using *cex.axis* and *ps* parameters but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `scales` argument with a list for the x and y axes works for me. The items in the list for scales would be able to be customized like the axis labels were.

```
library(caret)
m <- train(mpg~., data = mtcars, tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(2,4,5)))


plot(m, xlab = list(font=3, cex = 5),
     ylab = list(font=3, cex = 5),
     scales = list(x = list(font=2,cex=2),y=list(font=2,cex=2))
     )
```

[image: Plot with Custom Number Formatting]

Comment: plot.train calls a lattice / trellis, not your base R plot, so cex.axis doesn't work. You don't need that in your code above

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the code